# How do I style text fields in Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, browser, cross-browser

I haven't tested it on IE quite yet.

I want to style the background image and text box shape as well as borders for my search bar on my site, [dead site].

If you visit it on Firefox or Opera and see the search bar on the left column, that's what I am going for. Now if you visit it on Safari or Chrome, you should see that it is replaced by their default input text field, which makes the text illegible.

How do I style my text-box even on these browsers?

Comment: Just taking the black background/off-white text, this works fine in IE8 and IE7 (emulated). Your normal CSS should work, except for the rounded corners. [JSFiddle here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/7g3Bh/1/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be clear, on your site you are actually styling a *search* field and not a *text* field.

```
<input type="search"> <!-- This is what you have -->
```

vs

```
<input type="text">
```

To remove  the default styling and allow your css properties to work you need to change the `-webkit-appearance` property. This should do the trick:

```
#s {
    min-width:98%;
    background-color:#2a2a2a;
    color:#d3d3d3;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    font-size:.85 em;
    height:1.9em;
    display:inline !important;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: @mike: Please do not make substantial edits to my answer. If you have a suggestion you can put it in the comments.

Comment: The edit I made to your post is very similar to the edit you then made yourself. I shall also point out that I also added comments to your code which is good practice. Your answer was good but it was not complete. You are missing a few things (I added them in my edit but you have since removed them again). This site is all about collaboration, see here, http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing of which I shall cite the entry "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you."

Answer (score 0):

*style.css*

```css
body {
    background: #999 url(your_image_here.jpg);
}

.search {
    width: 295px; /* 300px less the 5px of left padding*/
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* same as height, then you can vertically align the text in the middle*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 24px; /* this gives 3px at the top and bottom */
    background-color:#ccc; /* a light grey background in the text box */
    color:#333; /* dark grey font colour */
    padding-left: 5px; /* spacing (padding) within the left hand side of the text box */
    border: 1px solid #000; /* 1px wide black border around the text box */
    display:inline !important;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px; /* slightly rounded corners, the order of the values is TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT */
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* this removed the default styling */
}
```

*index.html*

```html
<input type="text" class="search" value="search"> <!-- I've given the text box a value (search) so that you can test your css edits quickly without having to type in a value every time you refresh the page -->
```

I think that this answers your question. Get back to me in the comments if I can be of any further assistance.

Here is a link to jsfiddle where you can do a little rapid prototyping of my example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/nVDbA/